# libcurl, C, compiling example warning 'select@20'

Tags: libcurl

By compiling libcurl examples with gcc mingw+codeblocks on windows I found a problem:
This example:

```
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fopen.html
```

gives an error (NOT WARNING but error is not "quality" word for topic) during compiling:

> ...\fopen.c|134|undefined reference to `select@20'

On that line...

```
rc = select(maxfd+1, &fdread, &fdwrite, &fdexcep, &timeout);
```

How to get rid of that error?

Comment: That example is designed for linux.  `select` is a linux system call.  There might be a windows call that does something similar, but you'll probably have to adapt the example significantly to make it work.

Comment: At the top of that file is some preprocessor directives #ifdef WIN32 so I think it is enough... I will try to compile on linux anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try linking `-lws2_32` as that has a select() function, be it for network sockets, not file handles.
So it will probably compile but I doubt that select() line will work as it should.